# Obtaining elements at n to n+x in a sequence in fsharp

Tags: f#, sequences

Quite simply, given a sequence in F#, how does one obtain elements from index n to index n+x (inclusive)?

So, if I have a sequence like: `{0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5}`, how to I get the sub-sequence from index 2 to 4? It would look like `{2; 3; 4}`

Any answer that uses the massive built-in F# API is preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let slice n x = Seq.skip n >> Seq.take (x+1)
```

Note that if there is not enough elements in the sequence you will get an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: Something exactly like that!  I don't know how I missed the "skip" function.  Thanks!

Comment: It's generally good style to put the sequence parameter as the last one, so it can be used naturally with the `|>` operator.

Comment: You don't need `s`, actually: `let slice start length = Seq.skip start >> Seq.take length`

Answer (score 2):

```
let slice n x xs =
    xs
    |> Seq.windowed (x + 1)
    |> Seq.nth n
```

Note that unlike Yacoder's answer, it returns an array instead of a sequence (which may be want you want or not, depending on the situation).

I added my answer to show `Seq.windowed`, a very useful function IMHO. `Seq.pairwise` is also nice and good to know about.